# c# choose printer only working in main form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, printing

I want to print a DataGridView.
My code to print the view works finde but I've encountered a problem:
The code to choose the printer

```
PrintDocument _printDocument = new PrintDocument();
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.Document = _printDocument;
printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;
if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog())
{
     _printDocument.DocumentName = "Test";
}

PrintPreviewDialog objPPdialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
objPPdialog.Document = _printDocument;
objPPdialog.ShowDialog();
```

only works in my main Form (Form1).
In other forms he doesen't find a printer.

[Print dialog in other forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGnTP.png)

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Your disposing the dialogs/doc?

Comment: Use this to print datagridviews my dawg. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/DGVPrinter/dgvprinter.zip
very easy to use!

Comment: There isn't anything you can *normally* do to make PrintDialog unable to find any printers at all.  It is a very small class, all the real work is done by the operating system.  You'd have to invoke an act of God, like corrupting memory.

Comment: +Jelly your library seems to be verry good. Thank You.